# TypeScript - How to map a readonly interface for an object of varying depth with unknown keys?

Tags: typescript

As it currently stands with my application, I have my constants inside an exported const object across several files depending on the lib they are housed in. The depth of these objects is unknown although for all intents and purposes currently, the max depth is 2. The key is always a string and the value is also always a string.

I would like to make them readonly using an interface, or by some other means (ideally no libraries or Object.freeze due to the need to polyfill). Since these files will be changing all of the time I feel it is bad practice to map out each nested object inside an interface as well as the fact it is a lot of work.

Initially I have tried creating a recursive interface hoping it would work:

```
interface ConstantsInterface {
  readonly [field: string]: string | ConstantsInterface;
}

const CONSTANTS_MAIN: ConstantsInterface = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: {
        key4: 'val4,
        key5: {
           key6: 'val6',
           key7: 'val7'
         }
    },
    key8: 'key8'
}
```

...and so on. Bear in mind that this structure is an example and in reality it isn't as strict. I.e. there could be any number of entries in any position in a given object.

This interface didn't work as planned and resulted in certain keys throwing many 'type ConstantsInterface cannot be applied to type key1', or 'type [field: string] cannot be applied to type key2' etc.

I then proceeded to try to map out the depth as I felt that was the problem (although I shouldn't have since the depth could theoretically be any size) with:

```
interface ConstantsInterface {
  readonly [field: string]: string | readonly [field: string]: { 
  readonly [field: string] | string };
}
```

etc, and while this did solve some instances of the aforementioned error it ended up popping in some other places.

I am relatively new to TypeScript and I feel the answer lies in generics (or a different structure altogether, e.g. namespaces) but I have no idea how to apply such a thing.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than create a generic interface to describe your constant, I would rely on the inferred constant type and make it readonly by using [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
const CONSTANTS_MAIN = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: {
        key4: 'val4',
        key5: {
           key6: 'val6',
           key7: 'val7'
         }
    },
    key8: 'key8'
} as const;
```

The resulting type of `CONSTAINTS_MAIN` will have all `readonly` properties, and specific values.

You can give the type a name by using a type alias and `typeof`:

```
type MainConstants = typeof CONSTANTS_MAIN;
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I had no idea such a thing existed, it's always so simple. I'm guessing the alias can only be used on other variables that match the exact structure? I'm getting the 'type KEY: TYPE is not assignable to type readonly KEY'

Comment: Yes, `MainConstants` in that case would be only allowed on objects that exactly match. I was more thinking you might use the `MainConstants` as a parameter annotation somewhere, but you'd always use `CONSTANTS_MAIN` itself as the value.